# Operating System - Static linking is done by the Linker or Loader?

Tags: linker, operating-system, loader, static-linking

In the "Operating System Concepts", 9th edition, by Abraham Silberschatz et al., the authors said that:

```
"Some operating systems support only static linking, 
in which system libraries are treated like any other object module 
and are combined by **the loader** into the binary program image."
```

*(page 381, the 2nd sentence of the 1st paragraph of section 8.1.5*

I wonder that the linking (combining) is performed by the **Linker** or **Loader**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**(assuming GNU/Linux)**
I believe that's a typing mistake.
Static linking is done by the linker where you'd have a binary program image that contains your program's code and that of the library you're linking against; the loader will simply load your program as a whole.
Using Gnu C Compiler package, you may use static linking like this: `gcc -static code.c`
To check that the result indeed contains no markers for dynamically loaded libraries:
`ldd a.out` and you'll get a message like this: `not a dynamic executable`

When dynamically linking against a library, the linker will technically only leave a little marker in the resulting binary image stating that library 'x' needs to be loaded as well for your program to execute.
When the loader reads this binary image, it'll notice the marker and load the library; this action is never done in static linking because the whole thing becomes one large binary image.

Comment: I agree with you except the sentence: "the loader will simply load your program as a whole". Theoretically, we also have static loader which load the program as a whole, and dynamic loader which load the program partially into the memory.

Comment: @AnCongTran What do you mean by 'partially into memory'? Are you referring to copy-on-demand?